# Java: Sorting Data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, bundle

I am developing a health and fitness application that can store user information using sharedprefrences. These can later be viewed by the user. I can do this and display the information back inside a listview. when the user clicks the item in the listview, it loads a separate activity displaying the information. My problem is the information is always in a random order, I assume because I am using sharedprefrences. My question is it possible to sort this information so it always has the same order?

Images of my app working:

[image]

The image here is the screen where the user inputs information of an exercise and it is then stored using the save button.

Code:

```
public void saveLog (View view){

    EditText Date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDate);
    EditText Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    EditText Cal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCal);
    EditText STime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSTime);
    EditText ETime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editETime);
    EditText Entry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEntry);

    try {
        SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences("userData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userInfo.edit();
        Set<String> LogSet = new HashSet<String>();

        LogSet.add("Date: "+Date.getText().toString()+"\n");
        LogSet.add("Exercise: "+Name.getText().toString()+"\n");
        LogSet.add("Start Time: "+STime.getText().toString()+"\n");
        LogSet.add("End Time: "+ETime.getText().toString()+"\n");
        LogSet.add("Calories Lost: "+Cal.getText().toString()+"\n");
        editor.putStringSet( Entry.getText().toString(), LogSet);
        editor.commit();

        // show toast message for successful save
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "User data saved!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        String Grab = userInfo.getString ("Date" , Date.getText().toString());


    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // insert your own error message here
    }


}
```

The next image is the information being displayed inside a list.

[image]

code:

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);

    // Get ListView object from xml
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * 0);
    // ListView Item Click Listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int itemPosition     = position;
            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences("userData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userInfo.edit();
            String myString = userInfo.getAll().keySet().toString();
            String[] values = new String[] { myString };


            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityLog.this, Log_Data.class);
            //Create the bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
            bundle.putString("TAG", itemValue);
            //Add the bundle to the intent
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
            // ListView Clicked item index

            // ListView Clicked item value

            // Show Alert
           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });

}


@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences("userData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userInfo.edit();
    String myString = userInfo.getAll().keySet().toString();
   // String[] values = new String[] { myString };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1 );


    Map<String, ?> allEntries = userInfo.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {


        Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
        adapter.add(entry.getKey()+ ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    super.onStart();
}


public void showLog (View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNewLog.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}


public void deleteLog (View view){

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("userData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    settings.edit().clear().commit();
    getSharedPreferences("userData", 0).edit().clear().commit();

}

public void dataShow (View view){

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Log_Data.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

and the last image is the activity when the user clicks an item in the list. It loads all the information from that key.

[image]

code:

```
public class Log_Data extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log__data);
    TextView data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    //Extract the data…
    String something = bundle.getString("TAG");
    //Create the text view
    data.setText(something);


    }
}
```

Using bundle to pass data to the new activity. so is it possible to sort this data so it will say be displayed as Date,Name Of exercise, Start Time, End Time and Calories lost at the end? as of right now the data is always displayed randomly every new log entry.

Comment: Use local db(sqlite) instead of preferences.

Comment: well i dont want to change the use of preferences i just want to know is it possible at all to sort the information in its current state?

Comment: A set is unordered by nature. Use a list instead.

Comment: SharedPreferences are not what you want. That is only single key-value pairs. If you want a list of log entries, a database is the correct way to do so.

Comment: I might suggest you use Realm and have a `LogEntry` class, for example. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models

Answer (score 0):

I would recommened using a datebase via sqlite.